# Dedicated way to Cross-Compiling Open Source Softwares

Tags: linux, open-source, linux-kernel, arm, cross-compiling

I am very newbie in this kind of business. I have just cross compiled `Linux kernel`. But I have few question to ask which I have to know.

When we compile a Linux kernel I am using this piece of command, because my target platform is `ARM`.

```
make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-none-linux-gnueabi-
```

Could I `cross compile` any `Open Source` software like that or Is it depends on the software release that the software supports `cross compilation` or not?

The Linux kernel source contains a `arch folder` for separate architectures but `gcc`, `gLibc`, `binutils` doesn't have, why?

But those can be `cross-compiled`. **Can any one tell me why this kind of behavior happens?**

Is there any standard way to `cross-compile` different kind of software as per requirement?? Please lead me if any one proficient in this kind of business.

Thank you.

Comment: In rules it is mentioned that if you downvote question, you should explain why. IMHO, this question is totally correct.

Comment: This isn't a good question. What does it even mean "cross compile any Open Source"? For example can an open source project written in Java be cross compiled like this? Of course gcc and glibc has arch parts, check under sysdeps. Anything in this question can be looked up in internet.

Comment: @auselen ohhhhh. Hey hay.. java is platform independent, You don't need to cross compile .java files but you need to cross compile JRE or JDK environment to run the byte code on another architecture.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhetorical_question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a general way for cross compilation of software in linux if that is having configure 
script.

Extract the source code of the package that you want to install .

See whether that has any configure script in it.

If that is , then run 
./configure --help 
to find the options supported for compilation .

I usually use the following command to cross compile.

./configure --host=arm-none-linux-eabi --prefix=/path/to/where/you/want/to/install

Based on the package may be required to give additional options.
Examples like --with-out= libtiff etc.

If that is not having any configure script then tweak into the make file.

Comment: `--host=arm-none-linux-eabi` is it the `cross-compiler` prefix? Do I need to externally specify the library path which the `cross-compiler` using?

Comment: arm-none-linux-eabi is cross-compiler prefix. And ensure that the cross-compiler is in environmental variable PATH.                             i did not get the second question.

Comment: I mean those shared libraries automatically invoked by cross-compiler or do I need to set?

Comment: If those shared libraries are available in the PATH then the configure script picks that up automatically. If you do not want to have the support of some library then that can be skipped by using the option --with-out while configuring.

Answer (score 2):

The linux kernel has its own, very particular, build-system that is set up - not only for cross-compilation - but multiple architecture cross-compilation.  This is why a series of `arch` folders exists.

A large amount (but by no means all) of open-source user-space software uses [GNU autoconf](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/) to manage the configuration and build process.  The purpose of `autoconf` is somewhat different from the kernel build script - it allows software to be built on a wide variety of subtly different UNIX-like build hosts for a equally wide variety of build targets.

`autoconf` can be used used for cross-compilation with a bit of work.   There are [some hints](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.67/html_node/Hosts-and-Cross_002dCompilation.html)  here.  In principle, the build process needs to know:

- Which set of tools to use (e.g. gcc, binutils)
- Where the target's headers and libraries are staged
- Where to install the resulting product.

`gcc` and `binutils` are slightly special case in that cross-tools are installed on a development host alongside the host's own tools.  Since build processes might well use both, it's untenable that selection of tools is done entirely by the executable search path.  Instead, cross-tools are named with a target-specific name format - e.g.

`arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc`

and

`i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc`